# instantiate mix traits is compiling while single trait is not

Tags: scala

I have two traits

```
trait Person
trait Food
```

why this is compiling :

```
val pf = new Person with Food //OK
```

and this is not

```
val p = new Person //result  error: trait Person is abstract; cannot be instantiated
```

Comment: Note that you could create an instance of `Person` this: `new Person{}`.

Comment: @igx Open up the byte code and see what `new Person with Food` is doing. Chances are, they're creating an `Object` as syntactic sugar to allow for the `with Food` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traits are abstract (not instantiable) by definition. Even if they're fully implemented they may not be instantiated. As senia states in a comment, you can get an anonymous class from a fully implemented trait like this:

```
trait T1
val t1 = new T1 {}
```

Comment: Thanks, but in this case we will get java.lang.object with T1 , which is syntactic sugar. anyway please note that I didn't ask "how" but "why". but I get it - as @wheaties wrote and senia comment. it is just a syntactic sugar of creating an object

Comment: Why? That's how the language is defined. Abstract types are not instantiable. They can be made instantiable by turning them into a class (named or anonymous) and supplying unimplemented members (if any).

Comment: The question is why `val pf = new Person with Food` works, every one knows abstract class or interface or trait can't be initialized. but why it can be done using `with`,